# Functional equation $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+f(\frac{1}{1+f(x)})}$

Tags: functions

> **Problem:** Find all continuous real-valued functions $f$ such that
>   $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+f(\frac{1}{1+f(x)})}.\tag{1}$$

Here $f$ is allowed to be defined only on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

The only solutions I found are the constant functions
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\varphi},\quad\text{and}\quad f(x)=-\varphi,\tag{2}$$
where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio. I also proved that the only linear functions $f(x)=a+bx$ satisfying $(1)$ are the two above ones. I am tempting to conjecture that these are the only solutions but I failed to either prove or disprove it.

Comment: Does $f$ have to be defined for $1/\big(1+f(x)\big)$ whenever it is defined for $x$? Otherwise I can come up with lots of solutions...

Comment: @Patrick Setting $g(x)=\dfrac1{1+f(x)}$ might be a good start: $g \circ g = \dfrac1g-1$.

Comment: Starting with $y:=\dfrac 1{1+f(x)}\;$ and some work should give you $f(y)=\dfrac {2y-1}{1-y}$. (Oups Olivier was first here... :-))

Comment: Where did you find this problem? (I'm asking just out of curiosity)

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+f(\frac{1}{1+f(x)})}=\frac{1}{1+f(\frac{1}{1+f(\frac{1}{1+f(\frac{1}{1+\ldots})})})}=\frac{1}{1+f(f(x))}$ say $f(x)=a$ then $a=\frac{1}{1+f(a)}$ then $ f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-1$ where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

let $ 1+ f(x)= \frac{1}{y}$------[1]

by adding 1 on both side of given equation
$$ 1+f(x)=1 + \frac{1}{1+f(\frac{1}{1+f(x)})}$$

by [1] $$\frac{1}{y}=1+ \frac{1}{1+f(y)}$$

solving ahead will get us $f(y)=\frac{2y-1}{1-y}$

Comment: What if $f$ is defined recursively?